# Call Controller Action through Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have call controller action through javascript using window.location

```
window.location = "/SomeController/SomeAction/";
```

it's working fine but when i will develop it in on sub-domain it not constructing  URL properly

My URL Is

```
http://testgecianet/pms/
```

when i call the action it construct URL like

```
http://testgecianet/SomeController/SomeAction
```

instead of

```
http://testgecianet/pms/SomeController/SomeAction
```

how i can construct correct path when application deploy on SubDomain.?

Answer (score 2):

did you try using `@Url.Action` ?

For example your code of

```
 window.location = "/SomeController/SomeAction/";
```

could be written like

```
window.location = "@Url.Action("SomeAction","SomeController")";
```

This could solve the problem, I hope.